# How can I query this sql to get the best-selling product

Tags: mysql, sql

This's my database sample: 
*orderdetails* table with the ProID relate to *products* tabale

```
| ProID | OrderID | OrderQuantity | OrderPrice |
|  93   |    17   |       1       |     150    |
|  16   |    18   |       1       |     100    |
|  93   |    19   |       3       |     450    |
|  93   |    17   |       1       |     150    |
```

*products* table

```
| ProID | ProPicture | ProName | ProPrice |
|  93   | ./a.jpg    |  Iphone |    150   |
|  16   | ./b.jpg    |  Nokia  |    100   |
```

How can I get the best-selling product information: ProID, ProPiecture, ProName, ProPrice from *products* table base on *orderdetails* table?

Comment: What do you mean by `best seller`? Please add your sample output in a tabular format

Comment: Sorry it's the best-selling product

Comment: Total quantity? Number of total orders? Most revenue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a SQL join between the tables on ProID, e.g.

```
from products as p
inner join orderdetails as od
   on p.ProID = od.ProID
```

You can use *group by* syntax to ensure you get distinct rows, e.g.

```
group by p.ProID
```

Use aggregation function such as sum, count and avg to find out the totals in a select, e.g.

```
select sum(od.OrderQuantity) as total
```

Use *order by* syntax to show the top answers, e.g.

```
order by sum(od.OrderQuantity) desc
```

Use *limit* to show top n results, e.g.

```
limit 5
```

Hopefully that gives you enough pointers to formulate the SQL yourself.

**notes**, I've given the tables an alias to ensure you don't get conflicts between the column names. You can't reference *total* in your order statement due to the way SQL calculates the dataset. I've used an inner join, but you might want to look into left & right joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query -

```sql
select * from products where ProID =
(select ProID 
  from 
    (select ProID , sum(OrderQuantity) as total_order,
        max(sum(OrderQuantity)) over() as maxSm   from orderdetails
        group by ProID
    )
where total_order = maxSm)
```

Answer (score -1):

the Tested ms sql Query to Find Faster Selling product from above table

```sql
SELECT TOP(2) PRO.PRONAME, SUM(OD.ORDERQUANTITY) SALEQTY 
FROM PRODUCTS AS PRO INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERDETAILS AS OD 
  ON PRO.PROID = OD.PROID GROUP BY PRO.PRONAME
```